# mount.cifs not supporting 'multiuser'?

Tags: rhel, mount, multiuser

I was going to use the "multiuser" option for mount.cifs, but /var/log/messages reports:

```
kernel:CIFS: unknown mount option multiuser
```

- Kernel is 2.6.18-433
- mount.cifs is 1.12RH

I can't find information which version of mount.cifs is supporting multiuser. I guess RHEL 5.11 and its kernel are too old for it? Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [document](https://www.snia.org/sites/default/orig/SDC2012/presentations/Revisions/JeffLayton_Multiuser%20Mounts%20with%20Linux%20CIFS_revision.pdf) seems to say that `multiuser` was added in cifs-utils 4.7:

```
Originally by Igor Druzhinin in cifs-utils 4.7 and overhauled in 5.3. Kernel support in 3.3
```

The reference was rather oblique.  Corroborating information seemed needed.  [Version control](https://git.samba.org/?p=cifs-utils.git;a=commit;h=202f4b43209da32afc7ce5445a8f561c354c8f82) may indicate the same as [4.7](https://git.samba.org/?p=cifs-utils.git;a=log;h=refs/tags/cifs-utils-4.7) is where the `man` page was added:

```
manpage: add mount.cifs manpage entry for "multiuser" option
Jeff Layton [Fri, 8 Oct 2010 14:11:58 -0500 (15:11 -0400)]
manpage: add mount.cifs manpage entry for "multiuser" option

Signed-off-by: Jeff Layton <jlayton@samba.org>
```

Digging into the argument parser was a bit more challenging since `multiuser` is not present in the source code, so corroborating information was not located in other source files.

On the other hand, [this web page](https://www.thegeeksearch.com/how-to-perform-multi-user-smb-mount-in-centos-rhel-7/) talks  about using `multiuser` on CentOS 7, and says something like:

```
When a Samba share is mounted, the mount credentials determine the access
permissions on themount point by default. The new multiuser mount option
separates the mount credentials from the credentials used to determine file
access for each user. In CentOS/RHEL 7, this can be used with sec=ntlmssp
authentication (contrary to the mount.cifs(8) man page).
```

[http://rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&limit=19&srodzaj=1&dl=40&search=cifs-utils&field%5B%5D=1&field%5B%5D=2) shows cifs-utils 4.5 - 4.6 were native releases for RHEL 5, so it would not be surprising if it would not work, but, also according to [http://rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23866244/dir/redhat_el_5/com/cifs-utils-5.9-94.3.x86_64.rpm.html) cifs-utils 5.9 has been built for RHEL 5 (by another vendor), so perhaps there is some hope if one wanted to deviate from the distribution supplied packages.

The `"contrary to the mount.cifs(8) man page"` comment looks a bit like a red flag, in that `sec=ntlmssp` mentioned.  Have you used `multiuser` successfully elsewhere?

What exactly have you tried?  Please give actual examples.

Comment: RHEL5 is ancient and unsupported, so it is not a huge surprise it doesn’t have that feature.